# Possible to fetch Facebook application API secret?

Tags: facebook, fbjs

I'm using FB.Connect.createApplication (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/?u=facebook.jslib.FB.Connect.createApplication) to create applications on the fly. The problem is that the method doesn't return the API secret (only the app ID and api key). This is a big problem. Does anyone know if it's possible to fetch this data provided you have the application ID and API key?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out that what I'm trying to do is impossible. The next best solution is to create a child application, and make calls on its behalf (from the parent application).

Answer (score 2):

I dont think so. I know that some other APIs try to make secret keys nearly impossible to get through scripted methods for security.  Not sure about facebook but from the forums it seems like the createApplication() method was rolled out before it was completely finished. The consensus on the dev forums is that it will get rolled out ... eventually.